# Import LaTeX File into a Template?

Tags: templates, input

I have the following Task todo: I have made me a default structure for lecture notes and now I want to compile my notes into separate PDFs for learning.

So my goal is to have for every course a separate tex file, and have only one single template file. The problem is that I just can't do a `\input{myfile}` because I want to set the title, fancy page heads and stuff like that.
Or is this also possible with the `\input{}` function?

Or is there another way to go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set up the header/footer without the the actual contents defined.  So create a `MyTemplate.sty` which contains your setup.  Note here, that `CourseNumber`, `\CourseTitle` and `\CourseTitle` are not yet defined.  This file should have all the packages that you want to use and the basic setup of the style is done here.

#### `MyTemplate.sty:`

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Other generic packages

% Setup style for fancyheader
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\bfseries \CourseNumber} 
\chead{} 
\rhead{\bfseries \CourseTitle} 
\lfoot{\today} 
\cfoot{\Author} 
\rfoot{Page \thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% Other generic settings

% Following is only so that I can capture the image below in a small height. 
% Do not use in real document
%\renewcommand{\textheight}{4cm}
```

The for each course you have a separate file which includes `\usepackage{MyTemplate}`. Here is an example file where you define the values of the macros needed to fill in the contents of the header/footer. Note that this file should only contain the content, all the formatting info is contained in the `MyTemplate.sty`

#### `Math101:`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\usepackage{MyTemplate}

\newcommand{\CourseNumber}{Math 101}%
\newcommand{\CourseTitle}{Intro to Mathematics}%
\newcommand{\Author}{Prof. Reox}%

\begin{document}
\section{Section Header}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

This way each course will have a common format:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If your intent is to include only a single course `.tex` file with your template, then you set all your titles, headings, etc. in the course `.tex` file and use `\input{<filename>}` in your template file. Here's a brief illustration of what I'm talking about (you would have a number of `course.tex` files):

#### `course.tex`

```
% Course preamble
\usepackage{<packages>}% Course-specific package(s)
%...
\begin{document}
% Course body/content
\end{document}
```

#### `template.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}% Main document class
% Template preamble
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{<packages>}% Generic packages used throughout all courses
%...
% Other generic packages
% Other generic settings
\input{course}
```

The `\input{<filename>}` command extracts the contents of `<filename>.tex` verbatim and inserts it in a document where it is called. As such, you're able to include anything in `<filename>.tex` that you would normally in your main `.tex` template file. Just as long as the sequence of commands follow the regular/required document structure:

```
\documentclass{<class>}
%preamble
\begin{document}
%body
\end{document}
```

You'll note that, when `\input{course}` is replaced with the contents of `course.tex` in the first example, the above document structure will result, leading to a successful compile that is `course` specific.

As mentioned, this does not allow you to mix courses together and compile (say) `course1.tex` and `course2.tex` into your main template, since the each would have a preamble that would conflict with the regular document structure. If you *do* want this setup (for whatever reason), the you need to consider using something like the [`standalone` package/document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) or the [`subfiles` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles).

<sup>As an interesting side-note, consider reading [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you'd be best off (i) collecting all of your specialized code into a so-called LaTeX "style file" -- a text file that has the extension `.sty`, say, `reox.sty` -- and (ii) loading this package from each of your driver files. One loads a package with the `\usepackage` command, as in:

```
\documentclass{article} % or "report", or whatever
\usepackage{reox}
% further commands to set document's tile, page headers, etc
\begin{document}
% body of document.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your template command names e.g. \mytitle in the definitions for the headers etc. And then give in the course files this commands a sensible content — you only must make sure that you give the commands the correct content before using them.